# Resolve 500.23 integrated pipeline error WITHOUT touching app pool or integrated mode config

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-7.5, integrated-pipeline-mode

I'm running a development environment on which I have multiple sites running on IIS 7.5 and ASP.NET 4.0.

I had to update a few of those environments, and now I am getting the dreaded message that we all love:

> **HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error**
>   An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.

HOWEVER . . .  *all* of my environments are running ASP.NET 4.0 in integrated mode, and *none* of them have validateIntegratedModeConfiguration set to "false."

I know there's a way to resolve this without touching either of these configurations, but I can't find it anywhere.  *Every* resolution I've seen tells me to change one or the other configuration, and I do *not* want to do *either one.*

If all my other environments are working with these configurations, there has to be another setting somewhere.

Can someone help me out with this?

**Please do NOT tell me to "change from integrated to classic" or "change validateIntegratedModeConfiguration to false"; I will *NOT* accept either answer!!!**

Thanks in advance . . .